# How to post grouped input data within a form in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a form that contains 4 input fields.

```
<%= semantic_form_for @some_model, html: {class: "horizontal-form"} do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :person_id %>
  <%= f.input :car_id %>

  <%= f.input :person_id %>
  <%= f.input :car_id %>

  <%= f.actions do %>
    <%= f.action :submit, button_html: {class: "btn btn-primary"} %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

As you can see the input fields are identical.

I want to group these fields so they can be posted as an array like this:

```
[ [3838, 9090], [2938, 893] ]
```

Ang then i can be able to loop this array and fetch the data i need from an external api.

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

version of HTML

```
    <input type="textbox" name="person_id[]", value="person A">
    <input type="textbox" name="car_id[]", value="car A">
    <input type="textbox" name="person_id[]", value="person B">
    <input type="textbox" name="car_id[]", value="car B">
```

OR

```
    = simple_form_for @ some_model do |f|
    = f.input_field :name, multiple: true
    = f.input_field :name, multiple: true
    = f.submit
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you not create another field on your Model to hold the array.

Then create a Private controller method that runs when the form is saved and appends all the values to the array?